# Tcl strings to middle of binary file without overwriting its conten

Tags: file, binary, tcl

I have a binary file
in which I am trying to add a string in the middle of the file
(lets say after 10 Bytes)

I succees to overwrite the file with my string - but not to append
appreciate if someone can tell how can I append the string.

Here is my code example:

```
proc write_bit_header {} {
    set bit_hdr "#Here is my new string to be added#"
    set bit_hdr_len [string length ${bit_hdr}]
    set outBinData [binary format a${bit_hdr_len} ${bit_hdr}]

    set fp [open "binfile"  "a+b"]
    fconfigure $fp -translation binary
    seek $fp 10
    puts -nonewline $fp $outBinData
    close $fp
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you write to the *middle* of a file (which you'd *use the mode `r+b`* for), none of the other bytes in the file move around. They're still at exactly the same offsets within the file that they were beforehand. If you're writing a fixed-size binary record into the file, this is exactly what you want! However, if you're writing a variable sized record, you have to:

1. read *all* the data that is going to go after the bytes that you want to write
2. seek to the place where you want to do the insert/replace
3. write the data that you are inserting
4. write the data that you read in step 1
5. truncate the file (in case what you wrote in step 3 is shorter than what you were replacing).

Yes, this is non-trivial!

```
proc insertData {filename dataToInsert insertionPoint {firstAfterByte ""}} {
    # If you don't give the end of the range to overwrite, it's zero-length
    if {$firstAfterByte eq ""} {
        set firstAfterByte $insertionPoint
    }

    set f [open $filename "r+b"]
    chan seek $f $firstAfterByte
    set suffixData [chan read $f]
    chan seek $f $insertionPoint
    chan puts -nonewline $f $dataToInsert
    chan puts -nonewline $f $suffixData
    chan truncate $f
    close $f
}
```

It's much easier when you're appending, as you are not having to move around any existing data and never need to truncate. And you can use the `ab` mode so that you don't need to `seek` explicitly.

```
proc appendData {filename dataToAppend} {
    set f [open $filename "ab"]
    puts -nonewline $f $dataToAppend
    close $f
}
```

As you can see, the insertion code is quite a lot more tricky. It runs quite a bit of a risk of going wrong too. It's better to use a working copy file, and then replace the original at the end:

```
proc insertDataSafely {filename dataToInsert insertionPoint {firstAfterByte ""}} {
    set f_in [open $filename "rb"]
    set f_out [open ${filename}.tmp "wb"]
    try {
        chan copy $f_in $f_out $insertionPoint
        puts -nonewline $f_out $dataToInsert
        if {$firstAfterByte ne ""} {
            chan seek $f_in $firstAfterByte
        }
        chan copy $f_in $f_out
        chan close $f_in
        chan close $f_out
    } on ok {} {
        file rename ${filename}.tmp $filename
    } on error {msg opt} {
        file delete ${filename}.tmp
        # Reraise the error
        return -options $opt $msg
    }
}
```

Of course, not all files take kindly to this sort of thing being done in the first place, but the ways in which modifying an arbitrary file can make things go haywire is long and thoroughly out of scope for this question.

Comment: Of particular note, other programs that have the file open may get _very_ surprised by having things change out from underneath them (except in the append case, which is rather safer and pretty critical to how log files work…)

Comment: Hi Donal

Appreciate your answer - it did the work.

Comment: one small thing:
"chan copy" needed the "-size" in order to work for me:

chan copy $f_in $f_out -size $insertionPoint

Thanks,

Moshe